# add time result not correct in PHP

Tags: php, time, addition

I have problem with adding time which is not correct.
Example:
00:00 + 00:35 = 11:13

it should be 00:35 instead of 11:13

This is my code for above:

```
echo date('H:i',$total).' + '.$telat2.' = ';

if($telat2 == '00:00'){
    $total = $total;}
else{
    $total = ($total) + strtotime($telat2);}

echo date('H:i',$total).' ';
```

I hope everybode=y here could help me..

Thanks in advance..

**Update 1**

I have just got the right code!
This is the code:

```
$total_unix = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$total.':00');

$telat2_unix = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' '.$telat2.':00');

$begin_day_unix = strtotime(date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00');

$total = date('H:i', ($total_unix + ($telat2_unix - $begin_day_unix)));
```

I wonder how can this be happen?

Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: What values have `$total` and `$telat2` before executing this code?

Comment: From what I can see, you are trying to do this with timestamps, which won't produce desired results - almost ever - unless you have the full date attached to them, etc.  If you are just trying to work with to arbitrary times, do your addition and then break it down to hours:minutes, etc, manually.

Comment: Yes Jon, i only want to recap the amount of late a person from range of date.. So, just need to add the late-time only day by day.. Sorry my English is pretty bad.. :)

Comment: @michael The first row of record contain $total = strtotime('00:00'); $telat2='00:35';

Comment: Update 1 works as well as my solution.

Comment: Thanks everybody.. You are really helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a working code for original guestion:

```
 <?php

    function AddTime($telat1,$telat2)
    {
        $telat1 = date_parse_from_format("H:i", $telat1);
        $telat2 = $timeToAdd;
        $telat2 = date_parse_from_format("H:i", $telat2);


        $totalHours = $telat1['hour'] + $telat2['hour'];
        $totalMinutes = $telat1['minute'] + $telat2['minute'];
        if($totalMinutes >= 60)
        {
            $totalHours += 1;
            $totalMinutes -= 60;
        }
        if($totalHours >= 24)
        {
            $totalHours -= 24;
        }

        // Setting the leading zeros

        if(strlen($totalMinutes) < 2)
        {
            $totalMinutes = "0" . $totalMinutes;
        }
                if(strlen($totalHours) < 2)
        {
            $totalHours = "0" . $totalHours;
        }

        $total = $totalHours . ":" . $totalMinutes;

        return $total;
   }
   $timeNow = date('H:i'); // Base time
   $timeToAdd = '12:12'; // 12 hours 12 minutes to be added to $timeNow
   $total = AddTime($timeNow, $timeToAdd);
   echo $total;
    ?>
```

Comment: Wait, wait, what do i must do with your suggestion, im a bit confused here.. Sorry.. :)

Comment: I thought your question was how to add 'H:i' - formatted time to another 'H:i'-formatted time. Your original question didn't have requirements for date. Just time.

Comment: I got it, so when we have to add date formatted time to another date formatted time, it require date also not just time, right?
Thanks for your suggestion,buddy.. :)